# CentOS Live CD vs Live DVD download

Tags: linux, centos, livecd

In this download page, I am presented with some options: http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/CentOS/6/isos/i386/

What's the difference between Live CD vs Live DVD?

- CentOS-6.3-i386-LiveCD.iso 690M
- CentOS-6.3-i386-LiveDVD.iso 1.6G

Don't they just contain the same data? Why would I want to download Live DVD if Live CD is significantly smaller?

Comment: Should this be moved to unix.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks CentOS lacks proper documentation, but the difference is the different list of pre-installed applications.

Generally, there is no need to download the DVD unless:

- you have a poor home internet connection, but can download the DVD from somewhere else
- you're a bit lazy and prefer to download system with a wide scope of applications ready to use out-of-the-box

If you know exactly what kind of applications you are looking for, using LiveCD and just installing what you really need may be much better solution.

Answer (score 8):

Most probably the Live DVD contains packages the Live CD does not. Thus, for a one-time investment in a larger medium, and a continuous small increase in boot time each time the Live DVD is loaded, you would have additional built-in functionality as compared to the Live CD.

Additionally, if you were to use the Live medium as an install disc, you would have a "running start" with the DVD when it comes to included functionality.

Unfortunately, the [readme](http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/CentOS/6/isos/i386/0_README.txt) for the Live distribution does not list the included packages, and the links to the wiki within the readme have not yet been created.